# Does Monero have an equivalent of OP_RETURN?

Tags: transaction-data, blockchain-data

Or is there any other way of storing arbitrary data on the monero blockchain? If so what are the limits in terms of size, or anything else?

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/search?q=tx+extra

Comment: And https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6278/is-the-payment-id-the-equivalent-of-the-op-return-in-bitcoin